Group by slower after upgrading to pandas 2
We have a 7 GB file loaded to a dataframe.
grouped_df = df.groupby("constant")

After upgrading from pandas 1 to pandas 2, the above is stuck for hours. Is there any known issue with groupby in pandas 2?

Can you subset the dataframe to a subset which does finish? If you do, what's the speed difference between the two versions?

What's the dtype of the column you're grouping by?
